# stub and mock a subrotine for unit testing in perl

Tags: perl, mocking, stub

I am trying to do unit testing of the module. I need help and information , how to mock or stub a subroutine to test package.

I do not wish to use the module I came across on [cpan.](http://search.cpan.org/~simonflk/Test-MockModule-0.05/lib/Test/MockModule.pm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You an mock subs by overriding them in the following way in your test:

```
no warnings;
local *Foo::bar = sub {
    # do stuff
};
use warnings;
```

You typically want to set a variable to be checked later in your test inside your mock.

(even if I suggest using Test::MockModule, but you explicitly specified to not use it)

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell what conditions you might have to work around, because you don't give much detail. So this is a general overview of what's involved in mocking subroutines.

Perl stores package subroutines in the symbol table which we can access through ["globs"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#typeglob). Take the subroutine `do_the_thing` in package `Some::Package`, the last subroutine you assign to the *symbol* `*Some::Package::do_the_thing` will replace the normal functionality of that sub. We can also retrieve it so we can have it to call.

```
my $do_the_original_thing = *Some::Package::do_the_thing{CODE};
```

Note that to access it, we have to tell it to access the `CODE` slot of the glob. To replace the sub, we don't. Perl knows to assign code refs to the CODE slot of the glob.

```
*Some::Package::do_the_thing = sub { 
    if ( $_[0] eq '-reallyreallydoit' and $_[1] ) { 
        shift; shift;
        goto &$do_the_original_thing; # this does not return here
    }
    # do the mock thing
    ...
};
```

---

**NOTE:** The way shown demonstrates a minimal way to call a procedure so it acts *just like* the procedure you're mocking. If you don't like `goto`, then this does the same thing:

```
        #goto &$do_the_original_thing; # this does not return here
        return &$do_the_original_thing; # this returns here...to return
```

However, if you want to test what was returned, or store it to set up future tests, you could simply do it like this:

```
my $future_test_value ;
*Some::Package::do_the_thing = sub { 
    if ( $_[0] eq '-reallyreallydoit' and $_[1] ) { 
        shift; shift;
        my @res;
        if ( wantarray ) {
            @res = &$do_the_original_thing;
        }
        elsif ( !( wantarray // 1 )) { 
            $res[0] = &$do_the_original_thing;
        }
        $future_test_value = $res[0];
        return wantarray ? @res : $res[0];
    }
```

Comment: This is actually good. But is there a way using this without the goto statement?